# AWS IOT Core - Custom Authentication and ALPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core, quectel

I am building an integration between IOT Edge Quectel_BG96 and AWS IOT Core. The requirements are:

1. These IOT edges should authenticate using Custom Authenticator ( Username and password )
2. Quectel_BG96 has difficulties to implment ALPN. This means that I am not able to connect from the device, as there is no way for us to set this parameter in the TLS connection.

I built everything and all pieces are working as expected: Able to authenticate, able to pub/sub with no issues, BUT not from the modem Quectel_BG96.

My question to the community is: Is there away I can skip the ALPN requirement? Or to anything in AWS infra that plays as a middleware between two devices: Edge and AWS IOT Core?

Thank you in advance for any help

I tried connecting to AWS IOT Core using mosquito_pub and it works with no issues. I am expecting to be able to connect to AWS IOT Core from the iot edge and without setting up the ALPN.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, you can use mqtt over port 8883 without setting the ALPN. But it is with x509 certificates. Otherwise it is mqtt over websockets.

Here is the link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html